# spark [dataframe].write.option("mode","overwrite").saveAsTable("foo") fails with 'already exists' if foo exists

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark, overwrite

I think I am seeing a bug in spark where mode 'overwrite' is not respected, rather an exception is thrown on an attempt to do saveAsTable into a table that already exists (using  mode 'overwrite').

Below is a little scriptlet that reproduces the issue. The last statement results in a stack trace reading:

```
 org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Table `example` already exists.;
```

Any advice much appreciated.

```
spark.sql("drop table if exists example ").show()
case class Person(first: String, last: String, age: Integer)
val df = List(
    Person("joe", "x", 9),
    Person("fred", "z", 9)).toDF()
df.write.option("mode","overwrite").saveAsTable("example")

val recover1 = spark.read.table("example")
recover1.show()


val df3 = List(
    Person("mouse", "x", 9),
    Person("golf", "z", 9)).toDF()

 df3.write.
    option("mode","overwrite").saveAsTable("example")      

val recover4 = spark.read.table("example")
recover4.show()
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`saveAsTable` doesn't check extra options, use `mode` directly

```
df3.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).saveAsTable("example")
```

or

```
df3.write.mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("example")
```

Comment: spot on! thnx ;^)

Comment: This does not work. I tried 
```df1.write.mode('overwrite').saveAsTable('policy1')```. But I still get the same error. 
Can not create the managed table('`policy1`'). The associated location('spark-warehouse/policy1') already exists

Comment: @DurgaSwaroop did you find the solution to this? I'm getting the "already exists" error as well

Comment: The associated location already exists is a bit different case, have you tried setting `spark.conf.set("spark.sql.legacy.allowCreatingManagedTableUsingNonemptyLocation","true")` as described here - https://kb.databricks.com/jobs/spark-overwrite-cancel.html

Comment: That is not support anymore with Pyspark > 3